# I'm using axios to make a GET request for a Lord of the Rings API, I'm new to coding, and I'm failing to send the access key properly

Tags: javascript, api, get, axios

```
  componentDidMount() {

    axios.get('https://the-one-api.herokuapp.com/v1/movie',{key:'6DMnrpLiKW4BJK1_7X18'}).then((res) => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
```

this is a snippet inside a react component (React JS)

Comment: Documentation:
What about response formats and authentication?
The response format for all datasets is JSON. The API requires an access key for most routes. You can obtain an access token by signing up for an account here. All you need for setting up an account is a valid email address.
You need to send the access key as a bearer token in every request you make to the api. Bearer tokens must be included in the authorization header in the following format:
Authorization: Bearer your-api-key-123

Comment: https://the-one-api.herokuapp.com/documentation

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If yes, you should mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation of the page](http://the-one-api.herokuapp.com/documentation), you need send the Bearer Authentication header:

```js
const token = '6DMnrpLiKW4BJK1_7X18';
axios.get('https://the-one-api.herokuapp.com/v1/movie', {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
     }
})
.then((res) => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your headers should contain `Authorization: Bearer [key]`, so this should work:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(
        'https://the-one-api.herokuapp.com/v1/movie',
        {'Authorization':'Bearer 6DMnrpLiKW4BJK1_7X18'}
    )
    .then((res) => console.log(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```